# how to make my own session table in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an authentication api using DRF and it's admin using django framework. I've implemented token based authentiation of DRF in my API, everything works fine except when I login to admin-site it makes me automatically login to my DRF-api too without token. It creates a problematic scenario for me.

I think the problem is due to django's common session table. So I want to make a separate one to store api session details in a different table.

I don't know exactly what to do to eliminate this problem. Is my approach correct or not?

Please suggest me a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the session authentication from Django REST framework authentication list.